# I'm trying to use JavaScript and XPath on this basic xhtml page... but im getting no results?

Tags: javascript, xpath, xhtml

As the title describes, here is my basic xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var headings = document.evaluate('//h2', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
        var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();  

        var alertText = 'Level 2 headings in this document are:\n'  

        while (thisHeading) {  
            alertText += thisHeading.textContent + '\n';  
            thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();  
        } 

        console.log(alertText);
    </script>

</head>

<body>

 <h2>… Your HTML content here …</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

`Level 2 headings in this document are:`

Comment: Just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454143/greasemonkey-xpath-returns-no-results-for-xhtml-page)... looking into now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

web browsers process the html from top to bottom. Your script runs before the rest of the page exists. Move it down, or execute the code on the window onload event.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 XPath mistake: your content is in a namespace, but you are searching for it in no-namespace. You need //x:h2, with prefix x bound to the XHTML namespace.